# api with laravel and graphql

Tags: php, laravel-5, graphql, graphql-php

laravel intends to use REST. Controllers are directly bind to the routes. However when Graphql comes in, whole logic changes, there are queries and mutations which just have resolve functionality block. Is there a way to bind controller to graphql query or/and mutation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple implementation to connect the two. Especially if you're looking to benefit from all of the other functionality Laravel offers.

The best solution would be to make use of https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql . Not only does it have support for Laravel, but Lumen as well in the event you went with a micro solution purely for a REST. The library is also documented very well.